# What are 'estates of the House of Commons and the House of Lords'?

Tags: united-kingdom

Pls see green under-line below. I know what the House of Commons and House of Lords are, but I don't grasp "estates". What happens if I delete "estates of the"?

Colin Faragher. [*Public Law Concentrate* (1 ed 2019)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Public-Law-Concentrate-Revision-Study/dp/0198840527/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 124.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Estate is a rather old term for one of the three parts of parliament: Commons, Lords Temporal and Lords Spiritual (Bishops). I don't think it adds a lot to the context.

The Press are commonly referred to as the [Fourth Estate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Estate).

Comment: As an aside, some parliaments are called the "estates general."  Even farther aside, the Dutch *Staten Generaal* are the eponym of Staten Island, New York.

Comment: Here the  Lords Temporal and Lords Spiritual are treated as a single estate as they met (and still meet) together.